# Remove last 3 characters within a <div><a></a></div>

Tags: javascript, html, css, hide, ellipsis

I'm having an issue with some ellipsis being automatically added the end of a link with something I am pulling into my site. I really don't know javascript very well, and am trying to add something in to remove that!

Here's the code (with a fake link):

```
<div class="item-title-container">
  <a title="Brewery Packaging Technology Course" href="https://www.link">Brewery Packaging Technology Course...</a>
</div>
```

Here's what I've tried (3 different options):

```
let srch = '...';
document.querySelectorAll('.item-title-container').forEach(el => {
  if (el.innerText.indexOf(srch) > -1) el.innerText = el.innerText.split(srch).slice(0, -1).join(srch);
})

let element = document.querySelector('.item-title-container');
element.innerHTML.replace('...','');


var str = document.getElementsByClassName('item-title-container');
str = str.slice(0, -3);
```

I am obviously not very good at this but looking for a solution!

Comment: Are you sure it's three `.` characters and not a single ellipsis `…`?

Answer (score 1):

**Fixing the 2nd Approach**

`.innerHTML` allows you to access and set the content of a div or some other HTML tags.

However, you cannot edit the value of `.innerHTML`, this may sound confusing, here are some examples.

```js
var x = element.innerHTML; // access the content of element

element.innerHTML = "hello world"; // sets the content of element to "hello world"
```

You cannot access and set the content with the same `.innerHTML`, and that's what you tried by typing `element.innerHTML.replace('...','');`.

To fix that try,

```js
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace('...','');
```

**Fixing the 3rd Approach**

When `.innerHTML` is used to access the content, it does not return a reference to the content. That's the reason why the following code is not working:

```js
var str = document.getElementsByClassName('item-title-container').innerHTML; // you forgot to add .innerHTML here
str = str.slice(0, -3);
```

In the code above, editing `str` will only edit `str`. In other words, `str` is not reference to the element's `innerHTML`. In order to make the code work, you have set the `innerHTML` to `str`.

Try the following:

```js
var str = document.getElementsByClassName('item-title-container').innerHTML;
str = str.slice(0, -3);
document.getElementsByClassName('item-title-container').innerHTML = str;
```

To make the code above easier to read try the following:

```
var element = document.getElementsByClassName('item-title-container')

var str = element.innerHTML;
element.innerHTML = str.slice(0, -3);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an ellipsis character, not three `.` characters. You can use a regexp that replaces either.

```
element.innerHTML = element.innerHTML.replace(/(\.\.\.|…)$/, '');
```